# Upgrading laravel with 4 version difference

Tags: php, laravel

I have application runs with `laravel 5.4` and I like to upgrade it to `5.8` the task itself is easy I just need to change `"laravel/framework": "5.4.*",` to `"laravel/framework": "5.8.*",` but what worries me is **impacts**.

> The question is after i upgrading my app by composer file **do I need to
>   change any of source codes manually or no?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not upgrade directly from 5.4 to 5.8 since it's almost sure it would break your code. You should upgrade to each version and check the Laravel documentation on the changes.

For example, you can upgrade from 5.4 to 5.5 by following the guide [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade#upgrade-5.5.0), and then subsequentially for each version. Taylor and the community do a great job of documenting any required change in your codebase.

Comment: if that's the case then i think i prefer to move assets to fresh installed 5.8 version :)  thank you

Comment: In case you can afford it, I would recommend [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/). It's a great tool for upgrading Laravel projects.
BTW I have no relation with the product or its owners.